# QGIS: distance matrix different outputs

Tags: qgis, distance, qgis-processing

In one of my plugins I would like to use the distance geoprocessing algorithm. When running this algorithm from the menu Vector->Analysis Tools->Distance Matrix I get a different output than running the same function from the Geoprocessing Tools. (I am interested in the k*n matrix)

Unfortunately the output from the Geoprocessing Toolbox has different headers in the output and I need the result from the process run with the vector-analysis tools.

The first row of the processing output is

```
ID,DIST_1,DIST_2, ...
```

The Output of the menu-version is:

```
ID,4711,0815, ...
```

4711 and 0815 are my idnetifiers choosen in the dialog.

Is there a possibility to run this tool instead of

```
processing.runalg("qgis:distancematrix" ...
```

in my python plugin?

Comment: it seems like "qgis:distancematrix" is sorting the distances but you do not have the chance do identify the reltion between distance and "used points for distance calculation" in the table

Comment: I'm probably using a different QGIS and _Processing_ plugin version than you (QGIS 2.8.2 with _Processing 2.10.1_) and the first row from both the **Vector** menu and the **Processing Toolbox** are the same: `InputID, TargetID, Distance`. Which versions are you using?

Comment: you've choosen the k*nx3 option which does not produce a quadratic matrix.  I am talking about the second option : k*n